# If $f$ is total recursive and $A \subseteq \Bbb N$ is recursively enumerable then $f(A), f^{-1}(A)$ are recursively enumerable.

Tags: logic, recursion

Question: If $A \subseteq \Bbb N$ and $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ is a function, then let $f(A)=\{ n \in \Bbb N \mid \exists m \in A \text{ such that } f(m)=n \}$ and $f^{-1}(A)=\{ n \in \Bbb N \mid f(n) \in A \}$.
Prove that if $f$ is a total recursive function and $A \subseteq \Bbb N$ is recursively enumerable then $f(A)$ and $f^{-1}(A)$ are recursively enumerable.

I tried:
Definition. Let $B$ be a set of $\Bbb N$. $B$ is recursively enumerable if there exists a total recursive function $g$ such that $B= \{g(0),g(1),g(2),g(3),\ldots \}$.
So a set is recursively enumerable if it is the range of some total recursive function.

$\operatorname{rng}(f(A))=\Bbb N$ so $f(A)$ is recursively enumerable.
$f^{-1}(A)=A$ so $f^{-1}(A)$ is recursively enumerable.

Hints?

Comment: It looks like maybe you're using the letter $f$ for two different things. The $f$ in the given problem is _not_ the $f$ in the definition of "recursively enumerable"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your definition says of $A$ that there is a total recursive function $g$ that enumerates $A$, i.e., such that $A =\{ g(0), g(1), g(2), \ldots \}$. Let us fix some such function $g$, then we have:
$$
f(A) = (f(g(0)), f(g(1)), f(g(2)), \ldots \}
$$
so the total recursive function $f \circ g$ that composes $f$ with $g$ enumerates $f(A)$.

To show that $f^{-1}(A)$ is recursively enumerable, it is easiest to use an alternative characterisation of recursively enumerable set: a set is recursively enumerable if it is the domain of some partial recursive function. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set). If you don't know about this, please add a comment to say so and I can say more).
To see that $f^{-1}(A)$ is recursively enumerable according to this alternative characterisation, define a partial recursive function $h$, that given an argument $x$ first calculates $y = f(x)$ and then (with $g$ as in the previous paragraph) calculates $g(0)$, g(1), $g(2), \ldots$, halting when it finds an $n$ with $y = g(n)$. The domain of $h$ is then $f^{-1}(A)$.

As a small aside: it it usual to consider the empty set to be recursively enumerable. So the definition in terms of an enumerating function should say $B$ is recursively enumerable if $B$ is empty or if there exists a total recursive function that enumerates $B$.

Comment: What do you mean by this?: " that given an argument x first calculates y=f(x) and then (with g as in the previous paragraph) calculates g(0), g(1), g(2),…, halting when it finds an n with y=g(n). The domain of h is then f−1(A)."

Comment: I mean that the set of $x$ such that the computation of $h$ halts is $f^{-1}(A)$.